# How to customise progress bar ui in VideoSupportFragment of android leanback component?

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

I am building an android app for tv, where the ui requirement of video playback is completely different from the default one offered by VideoSupportFragment. Specifically I want to change the look and feel of progress bar of playback.
Not just remove the primary actions and secondary actions but rather remove the complete playbackrow ui and add my own custom ui.

[image].

Comment: are you able to achieve it?

Comment: @Shubham, unfortunately no.  I had to get away with leanback components and build my own fragment with exoplayer, which gives you all the control to customize the way you want.

Comment: How look & feel?
for the secondary progress you can override playbackProgressPrimaryColor
`code`<item name="playbackProgressPrimaryColor">@color/primary</item>`code`